# How do you analyze Domino snap files?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

The Domino server crashed with a java outofmemory error (HTTP). It generated a snap trc file (Snap.20160426.111944.4212.0007.trc). How can this be analyzed? It looks like IBM does have a TraceFormat jar file but that ships with Websphere from what I can tell and not with Domino (there is a TraceFormat.dat file in Domino).

Any suggestions on where to get this?

Howard

Comment: IBM support would seem like your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. I've never seen such a file on any Domino server. I'm more used to NSD files, which are a pain in the a** to read, but can at least help form an idea of what the server was doing around the time of the crash.

Anyway, one thing to know is that Domino ships with ridiculousy low default settings for JVM memory allocation. You may want to check the notes.ini for the parameter `HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize` : chances are it is set way below the actual capacity of the machine.

While you're there you could as well check other JVM related parameters such as `JavaMaxHeapSize`

Comment: Thanks, yes, those were set to be much higher, 3GB on this server for instance.